# Unfortunately Google Play Services stopped

Tags: google-play-services

I am using Xiaomi Redmi 3. All of a sudden, I found it continuously displays 'Unfortunately, Google Play Services has stopped'.

It happens so often, that I can't do any other work. I uninstalled that, then installed again from play store. But after installing, again that error message shows up

What can I do?

Comment: What did you uninstall? What is your Android version? Is your device rooted?

Comment: Please see: [Google Play Services Has stopped message continually popping up on my Samsung phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/122918/16575) / [Google Apps crashing, Play services crashing](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/125725/16575).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom rom, if so flash twrp and do a factory reset. i had the same issue and did every thing but doing a factory reset fixed the issue. do a back up in twrp first just incase.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem last two days ago and was pulling my hair out of this since none of the solutions found from internet are worked.

I solved by using this way:

1. Check your android version
2. Download playstore again, make sure your android version support the google play store apk.